HQL generate wrong cast
Having a cast like this:
SELECT
    CAST(a * 100000000 as big_integer)
FROM
    Amount
WHERE
    id = :id

Generate this SQL:
prepareStatement(
   "select cast(amount0_.\"a\"*100000000 as numeric(19, 2)) from \"AMOUNT\" where amount0_.\"id\"=?");

Question: Why two decimal places though?
There are some other problems

cast as Long in HQL - int8 in SQL (but long is bigger than int8)
cast as Double in HQL - float8 in SQL (but double is more precise than float8)

Using:

Hibernate-core-jakarta 5.6.15.Final
Postgres jdbc 42.7.4


Good question, but as a note that support for CAST() is up to the JDBC driver.  Why do you need to do this explicit cast?

@TimBiegeleisen I do not think the jdbc-driver is responsible for two digits precision. The SQL is generated by hibernate. The hibernate dialect might more likely have an impact to the SQL generation.

A similar question was asked here. The solution boiled down to something like
    @Override
    public void contributeTypes(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        super.contributeTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry);
        typeContributions.getTypeConfiguration().getDdlTypeRegistry().addDescriptor(
            new DdlTypeImpl(SqlTypes.NUMERIC, "numeric", this)
        );

and casting to BigDecimal. The reasoning, as Beikov presented was

You can register a custom DdlType into DdlTypeRegistry in a
TypeContributor for the NUMERIC/DECIMAL type code. The custom DdlType
can then override getCastTypeName to return just numeric if length and
precision are null.
This would be a nice improvement for Hibernate ORM though, so if you
could create a Jira improvement ticket in our issue tracker and
possibly also provide a PR with the improvement, chances are good that
we will accept this

